# SVN customize 403 error message

Tags: linux, debian, svn, http-status-code-403, forbidden

How can I customize "403 Forbidden" message? For only this message I want add additional info, like this "403 Forbidden (you have no rights to [URL to repository])" . How to do it?
I want to save compatibility with any svn tools, like native svn client, tortoise, java programmers environment etc.

--edit--

My environment:
OS: Linux Debian
SVN: 1.8.8
access protocol: HTTP(s) by Apache and DAV svn
auth protolol config: authzsvnaccess

All works like I want, except forbidden message. This misguide users. They think problem is with service, but really problem is with access rights.

Comment: A little more information would be useful. What's your server platform? Are you hosting through Apache or svnserve? Where are you expecting this custom error text to be visible?

Comment: You're Right. This is linux/debian and svn is served by apache. 403 is generated by apache authz because it keeps repository rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise error text/documents with Apache (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html) but that wouldn't help you here.

The error messages are embedded in to the client source (`subversion/libsvn_ra_serf/util.c`):

```
svn_ra_serf__error_on_status(serf_status_line sline,
                             const char *path,
                             const char *location)
{
  switch(sline.code)
    {
      case 301:
      case 302:
      case 307:
        return svn_error_createf(SVN_ERR_RA_DAV_RELOCATED, NULL,
                                 (sline.code == 301)
                                 ? _("Repository moved permanently to '%s';"
                                     " please relocate")
                                 : _("Repository moved temporarily to '%s';"
                                     " please relocate"), location);
      case 403:
        return svn_error_createf(SVN_ERR_RA_DAV_FORBIDDEN, NULL,
                                 _("Access to '%s' forbidden"), path);
```

Without looking, I suspect the other clients (SmartSVN, Tortoise) use the same or very similar HTTP client libraries, so you'd have the same problem: there's no facility for routing custom error messages from the server through to the client when the client is denied by password failure or authz.

However, if this is something you really need, then you might be able to special case the necessary path in the `pre-commit` hook, since when a hook script exists with a non-zero status, the contents of `stdout` are fed back to the user and you can have it say whatever you like.

The problem there is that the request would have had to be authenticated first, so a solution like this would likely break on  your permission model unless it was for a very specific, single case. (You could always customise the client, but I suspect that's further than you'd be willing to go for this)

Comment: very thanks for you detailed answer :) authorization is the first, but work after auth is second. then I see only one way for customize message, following your idea. I must drop authz, and implement restrictions into hook scripts. Thank you again for nice idea :)